# Writing custom functions in Sequelize Attribute

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT (SUM(total_time * actual_fte) / SUM(total_time)) AS actual_fte FROM USERS GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

I'm assuming it's some type of variant of this type of function:

```
attributes: [[models.sequelize.fn('SUM',models.sequelize.col('total_time')),'total_time']]
```

So, how would I turn this MySQL query into the sequelize version?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Sequelize.literal](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral)... It will be ok and you can do anything what you want ;)